# Why am I getting a straight line for my Polyline in MapKit?

Tags: swift, mapkit, core-location

I'm using Swift and created a mini App to play with, and so far the app is working the way I needed it for the route purpose, If I don't open another application over my app it works perfect for the route, however as soon as I open another app, it draws straight line from the time I opened and close the other App, as you see on the attached picture, it is impossible to take that route unless I'm flying with my car :) I know there is something that I'm missing, please help, sample picture is attached... [image]

Answer (score 0):

It was simple all I had to do is remove one of the pin and it works... :)